# Why i am not able to create the Unique pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I get c2664 error when i try to create a unique pointer

i did write the copy constructor as well as assignment operator but still i keep getting the 2664 error

```
class UndoCopyPaste : public UndoRedo
    {
    private:
        Container containerValue;
        bool valid;
    public:
        UndoCopyPaste() = default;
        UndoCopyPaste(Container* cont, std::string type);
        UndoCopyPaste(Container trans, Container* cont, std::string type);
        
    };
    
    class UndoRedo
    {
    private:
        std::string type;
    protected:
        Container* container;
    public:
        UndoRedo() = default;
        UndoRedo(Container* cont, std::string undoType);
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<UndoCopyPaste> undoCopyPastePointer = std::make_unique<UndoCopyPaste>(new UndoCopyPaste()); // error C2664: 'UndoCopyPaste::UndoCopyPaste(UndoCopyPaste &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const UndoCopyPaste &'
```

Comment: Because `new UndoCopyPaste()` is an rvalue. Remove the new operator

Comment: Do you mean `auto undoCopyPastePointer = std::make_unique<UndoCopyPaste>();`?

Comment: Concerning the rollback edit, **c++ tag is not unnecessary** since this is a c++ question. Moreover the OP is free to specify which standard versions his code is required to support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code with `make_unique`:

```
x = std::make_unique<Foo>(a, b);
```

is essentially equivalent to this:

```
x = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(a, b));
```

Note that the `a, b` pass to `make_unique` gets passed directly to the constructor of `Foo`. So your code

```
std::make_unique<UndoCopyPaste>(new UndoCopyPaste());
```

is equivalent to this:

```
std::unique_ptr<UndoCopyPaste>(new UndoCopyPaste(new UndoCopyPaste()));
```

You're actually passing `new UndoCopyPaste()` to the constructor of `UndoCopyPaste`! So just take out that parameter altogether:

```
std::make_unique<UndoCopyPaste>();
```